# Como fazer números aleatorios

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Olá alguém saberia me dizer qual o nome desse efeito que tem nesse site :

http://www.popupdesign.com.br/

assim que rolar a pagina acima do fale conosco existe 4 imagem e embaixo dela gera um numero gostaria de saber qual o nome deste efeito e onde posso encontra-lo.

Comment: O número não é gerado aleatoriamente, ele foi colocado lá. O nome do efeito é `FLIP` http://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-css-3d-flip-card/.

Comment: sim amigo mais vc percebeu como ele faz eleconta alguens números antes de inserir eles eu vi ele no jquery plugin porém não achei que um dia fosse precisar e assim não me lembro qual o nome disso porem sei que tem no site da jquery plugin

Comment: isso lhe ajuda? http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/ Repare que a contagem começa do 0 e vai até o número pretendido.

Comment: Também tem esse plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html

Comment: opa era isso mesmo amigo "vlw" porem o link com resposta para eu aceitar se quiser

Comment: Uma dica, sempre que responder a um comentário de alguém na sua pergunta, pressione o "@" (arroba) que irá aparecer o nome do utilizador e selecione, assim ele irá receber uma notificação e saberá que você respondeu ao comentário. Por exemplo, o @natan agora irá receber uma notificação porque o mencionei no meu comentário. Fica a dica!

Comment: Opa obrigado @FilipeMoraes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja esse plugin: http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Animating-Numbers-Counting-Up-with-jQuery-Counter-Up-Plugin.html

Implementação:

Inserir as bibliotecas abaixo no seu código. Fazer o donwload dos arquivos no site acima. Não esquecer de incluir o Jquery também:

```
<script src="js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
<script src="waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Definir o tipo de conteúdo dentro da tag span:

```
<span class=".integers">12345</span>
<span class=".floats">123.45</span>
<span class=".numbers-with-commas">12,345.00</span>
```

Executar o plugin, no exemplo abaixo foi aplicado diretamente a qualquer tag "span":

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('span').counterUp({
        delay: 10, // atraso de 10 ms
        time: 1000 // velocidade do contador de 1000 ms
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: cara uma outra duvida mais acho que terei que abrir outro tópico mais se "vc" entrar novamente no site acima do efeito que falei existe um texto em rosa que fica passando se sabe "tbm" se tem um puglin para isso

Comment: @Kirito conheço esse plugin: http://bxslider.com/ o exemplo que aparece na página principal pode ser editado para ter o mesmo efeito que você pretende.